# Using autojump on Centos Linux with zsh gives error?

Tags: linux, centos, autojump

On Centos Linux, switching to zsh causes autojump to give me this error:

```
-bash-4.2$ zsh
/etc/profile.d/autojump.bash:13: command not found: complete
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the project's [README](https://github.com/wting/autojump#linux):

> RedHat, Fedora, CentOS (install autojump-zsh for zsh, autojump-fish for fish, etc.)

I have installed it with `sudo yum install autojump-zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.zshrc`, you must source **autojump.zsh**, not **autojump.bash**
(I do not know where it will be located on a CentOS, but it will be in same folder as autojump.bash).

On Ubuntu, here is what you need to append at the end of your `.zshrc`:

```
source /usr/share/autojump/autojump.zsh
```